# Is there something like an ad-hoc approach in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction

When we use a machine learning approach, we divide the data set into test and training data and, in effect, we always use a post hoc approach by using all the data and then calculating the y-value for a new query.

But is there such a thing as an ad hoc approach where we can go through feature by feature for a new query and see how our prediction changes?

The advantage of this would be that we know exactly which feature has changed the predictions and how.

I would be grateful for any advice, including literature references, as I don't really know how to google it. It is also possible that the term ad-hoc approach is not chosen correctly.

Comment: This really isn't on-topic for stack overflow, which is for specific *programming questions*. I suggest using another stack exchange network, e.g. [statistics.se] or [ai.se]

Comment: Please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 0):

Very vague question. Also, why would you know how the prediction changes? You usually want to know which feature contributes most towards finding the 'best' prediction/correct classification. That is approached by looking at **Feature Importance** which comes in different flavors for different algorithms.

In case that is kind of what you were looking for take a look at *Permutation Feature Importance*, *Boruta Algorithm*, *SHAP Feature Importance*, *Feature Importance for tree-based algorithms*, ...